# jQuery animate() page scrolling up and down alone

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

Hi I am quite new to jQuery. I am trying to make the page scroll the height of the window and using jQuery to smoothly do so. When I am using the code below, the page keeps scrolling up and down continuously. An idea why?`

```
var body = jQuery('body, html');
var newDistance = 0;
var movement;
var newPosition = 0;

jQuery(window).on('scroll',function(){
    movement = window.pageYOffset;
    var winh = window.innerHeight;
    if(movement >= (newPosition + 100)){
            newDistance += winh;
            jQuery(body).animate({scrollTop:newDistance},{
            duration: 'slow'
            });

            console.log('newd', newDistance);
            newPosition = newDistance;
     }else if (movement <= (newPosition - 100)){
            newDistance -= winh;
            jQuery(body).animate({scrollTop:newDistance},{
            duration: 'slow'
            });
            newPosition = newDistance;
    }else{
            jQuery(body).animate({scrollTop:newPosition},{
            duration: 'slow'
            });
    };
 } );
```

Comment: I think this is because `scrollTop` also fires a `scroll` event. So what really happens is that the first time you trigger `scroll` event, it goes into callback, animates `scrollTop` which in turn fires another `scroll` event which comes back into callback and hence a never ending loop.

Comment: how would you try and go about it? feel exhausted

Comment: I think you can set a boolean flag (e.g. `isAnimating`) on the `window` scope and set it to `false` initially. And then inside your `scroll` callback, the first thing you do is to check for this boolean flag's value to be `false`. Put everything inside this `if` clause. And then inside the `if` clause, you can set `isAnimating` (or whatever name you gave it) to `true`. Also, you set it back to `false` inside `complete` callbacks of your `animate` methods. Makes sense? Can you share a fiddle so I can play around to see if what I am suggesting is even to going to work in the first place?! :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gan13myx/ this the link

Comment: can you put some HTML as well as some CSS so we can actually see the animations in action :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gan13myx/1/ sry for that

Comment: Ah I see now what you are trying to do. Although, based on my suggestion earlier, this is what I could create: https://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/jLwsoj70/.

Comment: But as you'll notice, I think this produces unwanted *glitches* whilst scrolling. I think this is not as easy as I thought it would be. Let me see what I can do with it.

Comment: Thanks Tahir, it definetely works better than mine:)

Comment: better, but not really the best-est solution to be honest.

Comment: I saw http://www.dishoom.com/ this site, thought it wouldnt be difficult!!, but was wrong

Comment: In the website you mentioned, if you notice, the animation only happens when you use `mousewheel` but if you simple `drag` the scrollbar or even use up & down arrow keys, the animation does not happen.

Comment: yes i intend to use it only on tablets/mobiles. Thanks for your help!